# Is there any compatibility between HTML canvas and SVG or are they completely separate beasts?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, canvas

I should not be asking "what is better"  but here is the problem:

I have chemical structure (MOLFILE) drawing coded using HTML canvas. I have a Conway Game of Life coded using canvas. The canvas coding seems easy and standardized, and it comes with a great feature I used in the Game of Life case, which is the canvas media recording that is very easy (the Canvas Recorder code is just a few lines of code.)

But I also use some D3 for forced based layout of natural structures where I have no absolute positioning like I have with Conway Life and with the MOLFILE drawing. And I need to combine the MOLFILE drawing with the D3 force based layout. Also, yesterday I checked if I can use the Canvas Recorder to record the animated SVG I get from D3 force based layout. And the only code I found seemed to copy the SVG drawings into a canvas to then use the canvas media recording feature. Very strange.

My question is: shouldn't SVG and canvas be somehow compatible? Don't browsers ultimately use the same underlying 2D graphics engine for both SVG and canvas? How can the two be mixed? Does D3 have a canvas version or is it only for SVG? Is there a canvas based alternative to D3, especially for force directed layout?

This will help me decide what I should retain as fixed and what I should move. I could port the MOLFILE drawing to SVG. Or I could port the force based layout stuff to canvas. Something's gotta give. Ideally there would be some compatibility layer so I don't need to port anything and could use them together. But speed, efficiency is an issue as my drawings have thousands of nodes and arcs.

Comment: No, SVG and Canvas are two separate technologies. But you can find a lot of resources and attempts by users to do that on Google if you look there.

Comment: Wondering why there so some much dislike against this question (and its answer). It may seem a bit broad at first, but I believe OP made a good job at narrowing the problem to a perfectly valid and non obvious question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> shouldn't SVG and canvas be somehow compatible?

Yes and no...
An SVG image is in between an HTML page (as a language, it's based on XML), and an image (at the end, its graphic rendering is what matters).
As a graphic engine, it does share a few concepts with the canvas API, and work is done at least on the canvas API side to indeed come up with more unified APIs. For instance the Path2D interface does accept an SVGPath declaration string as input, there are also discussions to expose a new CanvasFilter interface based on SVGFilters etc.

All that can be done on an SVG can also be done on a canvas, but for most of it, you'll have to write the rendering code yourself instead of letting the browser handle it.

> Don't browsers ultimately use the same underlying 2D graphics engine for both SVG and canvas?

Yes both at the end fall in the same Skia / Cairo / WebRender / Direct2D painters, but so does HTML+CSS. So this doesn't mean much. The APIs are still very different.

> How can the two be mixed? Does D3 have a canvas version or is it only for SVG?

Although D3 was written with SVG in mind, and some of its methods (like transitions) works best with DOM nodes, a lot of its tools don't really depend on anything else than JavaScript.
You pass some data to it, it helps transform it, generate coordinates / color / whatever.
So no, there is not a canvas version of D3, but you can use D3 to help you draw on a canvas, there are many articles on the web explaining how to do various things with D3 on a canvas, because yes, all isn't straightforward.
For a force-directed-graph, it shouldn't be too hard though.

---

Regarding why you can't use a MediaRecorder to record an SVG like you can do with a canvas, among other things, SVG does expose far more sensitive information than a canvas.

For instance you could have an svg like:

```html
If this rectangle is red it means you already visited <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66663899/is-there-any-compatibility-between-html-canvas-and-svg-or-are-they-completely-se">that link</a><br>

<svg width="50" height="50">
  <style>
    rect { fill: green; }
    :visited rect { fill: red; }
  </style>
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66663899/is-there-any-compatibility-between-html-canvas-and-svg-or-are-they-completely-se"><rect width="30" height="30"/></a>
</svg>
```

When drawing it on a canvas, the browser can tamper all the privacy holes, but doing this at monitor's frame-rate to produce a video? Will probably never happen.

```js
const svg_markup = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString( document.querySelector("svg") );
const svg_blob =  new Blob([svg_markup], { type: "image/svg+xml" });
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const img = new Image();
img.src = URL.createObjectURL(svg_blob);
img.onload = (evt) => {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0 );
}
```

```html
If this rectangle is red it means you already visited <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66663899/is-there-any-compatibility-between-html-canvas-and-svg-or-are-they-completely-se">that link</a><br>

<svg width="50" height="50">
  <style>
    rect { fill: green; }
    :visited rect { fill: red; }
  </style>
  <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66663899/is-there-any-compatibility-between-html-canvas-and-svg-or-are-they-completely-se"><rect width="30" height="30"/></a>
</svg><br>
When drawn on a canvas :visited and others are tampered.<br>
<canvas width="50" height="50"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank! Excellent detailed answer. Of course, the SO format does not allow you to give even more facts about the differences between canvas and SVG, but already enough for understanding